# Почему git не собирается с помощью make?

Tags: cmake

Я скачал git версии 2.41.0

Затем выполнил `make configure` в папке с git и `./configure --prefix=/usr` как написанно в файле INSTALL (Я особо не понимаю что значат эти команды, поэтому в `./configure` оставил `prefix=/usr`

После`make; make DESTDIR=~/home/tmp/git install` выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
LINK git
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file git: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2399: git] Error 1
```

Так же я немного поменял название папки родителя папки git. И после этого ошибка изменилась:

```
LINK git-remote-http
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file git-remote-http: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2802: git-remote-http] Error 1
```

Я такой путь `DESTDIR` выбрал потому что хочу удалить *git* из системы, `DESTDIR` образует иерархию файлов чтобы я потом знал что удалять. В предидущий раз устанавливал просто через `make install`. Просто у меня почему то `git clone` не работает, я решил удалить *git* перед установкой новой версии из исходников

Я изменил папку родителя с `Manualy_installed_programs` на тоже самое имя, только с маленькой буквы. Странное вообще заметка, может она поможет понять в чем ошибка. Когда я опять вернул предидущее имя папки ошибка изменилась на первую. Не понимаю как это так (Наверное просто порядок выполнения не определен и может зависит от неопределённых факторов)

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял зачем сначала указывать `--prefix=/usr`, а потом ставить куда-то в `~/home/tmp/git` (кстати, это вообще *очень* странный путь). И где собственно компиляция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Обновил папку с исходным кодом, перекачав архив и распаковав его
2. Убрал из *bashrc* строку `alias ls="lsd"`

Что-то из этого помогло